# Read access to a login in MS SQL schemas

Tags: sql-server

We have a MS SQL Server login and created users belonging to that login in several databases. We want to grant read access to all tables in the databases to these users. What query can we run to grant the read access?

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that the database user is not present in every user database, but only in some?

Comment: @hot2use we create one user per database we want to give access to that login so yes users are created for the databases we want that login to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably grant `db_datareader` access to that user.
Members of the `db_datareader` fixed database role can read all data from all user tables.

```
USE master
GO

DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(32)   
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @User VARCHAR(64)
SET @User = '[MyUser]' --Your User

DECLARE Grant_Permission CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT name FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN Grant_Permission  
FETCH NEXT FROM Grant_Permission INTO @DatabaseName  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    SELECT @SQL = 'USE '+ '[' + @DatabaseName + ']' +'; EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'', ' + @User + ''

    --EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    PRINT @SQL

FETCH NEXT FROM Grant_Permission INTO @DatabaseName  
END  
CLOSE Grant_Permission  
DEALLOCATE Grant_Permission
```

With this permission in-place, you won't need to grant read access every time you create a new table.

Comment: Dang, thought I'd be first to answer a question finally. >.<

Comment: It looks as if this script is trying to grant read access to all non-system databases. We want to allow read access to some of the databases.

Comment: Well.. In order to do that you just need to change the where clause from sysdatabases, specifying the names you need.

Comment: @SandahAung did you have any luck with my script? It should only do the users that belong to each of their respective databases and you can add to the filter on the master.sys.databases table in the first SELECT statement for any other databases you want skipped. Let me know if you need any help. :)

Comment: I accomplished my task by modifying your script a little. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to do this without needing a temp table, but in the interest of time (it's almost 1AM by me), this is my v1 of essentially doing the same thing @Dan recommended but without needing a cursor.

Also, it'll automatically adjust all user's permissions for you on execution, instead of needing to pass in one user at a time via a parameter.

```
-- Temp table of all applicable users in their respective databases (to be used in dynamic SQL later on)
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_UsersByDatabase 
(
    UserName VARCHAR(500),
    DatabaseName VARCHAR(500)   
)

DECLARE @Sql_GetUsersByDatabase AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

-- Sets up dynamic SQL script to get all users from all databases and load into our temp table
SELECT @Sql_GetUsersByDatabase = @Sql_GetUsersByDatabase + 
'INSERT INTO #TEMP_UsersByDatabase 
SELECT [name] AS UserName, '''
+ d.[name] + ''' AS DatabaseName
FROM [' + d.[name] + '].dbo.sysusers
WHERE hasdbaccess = 1 and [name] <> ''dbo''; ' -- hasdbaccess = 1 -- I believe this filters out non-relevant user accounts, but this filter can be removed if problematic
FROM master.sys.databases AS d
WHERE d.[name] NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

--SELECT @Sql_GetUsersByDatabase -- FOR TESTING

EXEC (@Sql_GetUsersByDatabase);

DECLARE @Sql_AlterUserRoles AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

-- Sets up dynamic SQL script to alter the roles and provide db_datareader to each user of each database respectively
SELECT @Sql_AlterUserRoles = @Sql_AlterUserRoles + 'USE [' + ubd.DatabaseName + '] GO ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER ' + ubd.UserName + '; '
FROM #TEMP_UsersByDatabase AS ubd

EXEC (@Sql_AlterUserRoles)

--SELECT @Sql_AlterUserRoles -- FOR TESTING

-- Final cleanup
DROP TABLE #TEMP_UsersByDatabase
```

Note: I assumed you were using at least SQL Server version 2012 (or greater), but if you're on a lower version of SQL server (e.g. 2008 R2) then replace the dynamic SQL @Sql_AlterUserRoles line of code with this:

```
SELECT @Sql_AlterUserRoles = @Sql_AlterUserRoles + 'USE [' + ubd.DatabaseName + '] GO EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, ' + ubd.UserName + '; '
```

The difference is you need to call the sp_addrolemember procedure on SQL 2008 R2 instead of using "ALTER ROLE".